# Ext.grid.Panel xtype ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

What's the xtype of Ext.grid.Panel. Also please tell me how can i find the xtype of any class.

Thanks

Comment: Your two questions are unrelated to each other. Please consider to split them into two separate questions.

Comment: true they are unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the xtype in the [online documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel), it appears with the name of the class in the title. In your case Ext.grid.panel use the xtype `gridpanel`.

Comment: thanks sergio, Could you please tell me how can i set the height of each row and background color for the list view.please..

Comment: @dev I think you should open another question with that. Also, post the code that you've tried. :)

Comment: Please answer this one two http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751028/extjs-4-grid-customization-total-row-at-the-end

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the `getXType()` method on any `Extjs 4` component. This will return the string that represents the component `xtype`.